# Looking for examples of holomorphic maps to $\mathbb{P}^1$ with certain property

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I would like to know any example of nonconstant holomorphic map $f:X\to\mathbb{P}^1$ such that $K_X\cong f^*\mathcal{O}(2n)$ for some positive integer $n$, where $K_X$ is the canonical bundle of $X$.

In the case that $X$ is a Riemann surface and $n=1$, this is related to sections of spin bundle (theta characteristics) on $X$. Numerous examples can be constructed.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider a hypersurface $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^r$ whose associated invertible sheaf is isomorphic to $\text{pr}^*_{\mathbb{P}^1}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2n+2)\otimes \text{pr}^*_{\mathbb{P}^r}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}(r+1)$.

Comment: Any elliptic surface over $\Bbb{P^1}$ with irreducible fibers.